# addPageRequestListener always fetching page even no scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, infinite-scroll

can anyone help me, i want to load the next item when scroll down or load more action only
but when i load the page, it keep load next item and never stop, can anyone help me

```
class DashboardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<DashboardWidget> createState() => _DashboardWidgetState();
}

class _DashboardWidgetState extends State<DashboardWidget> {
  dynamic leads = null;
  dynamic creditBalance = null;
  dynamic managers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initData();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> initData() async {
    final token = Application.preferences?.getString('api_token') ?? "";
    final response = await Api.getLeads(token: token);
    dynamic managerIds;
    if (isUserManager()) {
      var managers = await Api.getUserSettings(
        token: token,
        params: {"manager": Application.preferences?.getString('id')},
      );

      managers = jsonDecode(managers.data)['data'];
      managerIds = managers.map((e) => e['id']).toList();
    }

    final partner =
        jsonDecode(Application.preferences?.getString('partner') ?? "");

    final managersData = await Api.getUserSettings(
      token: token,
    );
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        creditBalance = partner['partner_credit_balance'].replaceAllMapped(
          RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'),
          (Match match) => '${match[1]},',
        );
        leads = jsonDecode(response.data);

        if (isUserDesigner() ||
            (isUserDirector() &&
                Application.preferences!.getBool('company_view') == false)) {
          leads = leads
              .where(
                (lead) =>
                    lead['manager_id'] ==
                    int.parse(Application.preferences?.getString('id') ?? ''),
              )
              .toList();
        } else if (isUserManager()) {
          leads = leads
              .where((lead) => managerIds.contains(lead['manager_id']) as bool)
              .toList();
        }

        leads = leads
            .where(
              (lead) => [
                'Follow up (uncontactable)',
                'Follow up (discussion)',
                'New',
              ].contains(lead['heat_type_name']),
            )
            .toList();

        leads = groupBy(
          leads,
          (obj) => (obj! as Map<String, dynamic>)['grouped_lead_won_date'],
        );

        managers = jsonDecode(managersData.data)['data'].where((e) {
          if (isUserManager()) {
            return e['manager_id'] ==
                    Application.preferences?.getString('id') ||
                e['id'].toString() == Application.preferences?.getString('id');
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }).toList();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      color: dangerColor,
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            leads = null;
            creditBalance = null;
            initData();
          });
        }
      },
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        FollowupLeads(
                          counter:
                              leads != null ? leads.length.toString() : "0",
                        ),
                        TotalRewards(
                          counter:
                              leads != null ? creditBalance.toString() : "0",
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              Center(
                child: LeadsTable(leads: leads, managers: managers),
              ),
            ]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LeadsTable extends StatefulWidget {
  const LeadsTable({super.key, required this.leads, required this.managers});
  final dynamic leads;
  final dynamic managers;

  @override
  State<LeadsTable> createState() => _LeadsTableState();
}

class _LeadsTableState extends State<LeadsTable> {
  static const _pageSize = 2;

  final PagingController<int, dynamic> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    try {
      if (pageKey < 30) {
        final token = Application.preferences?.getString('api_token') ?? "";
        var newItems = await Api.getLeads(token: token, params: {
          "pageKey": pageKey,
          "pageLimit": _pageSize,
          "status": {"0": 3, "1": 4, "2": 42}
        });

        newItems = groupBy(
          jsonDecode(newItems.data),
          (obj) => (obj! as Map<String, dynamic>)['grouped_lead_won_date'],
        );
        var list = [];
        var length = 0;
        newItems.forEach((k, v) => {
              list.add(LeadModel(k, v)),
              length += v.length as int,
            });

        final isLastPage = length < _pageSize;
        if (isLastPage) {
          _pagingController.appendLastPage(list);
        } else {
          final nextPageKey = pageKey + length;
          _pagingController.appendPage(list, nextPageKey as int?);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          PagedListView<int, dynamic>(
            // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            primary: false,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            pagingController: _pagingController,
            builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<dynamic>(
              itemBuilder: (context, index, item) {
                String key = index.date;
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 20,
                        vertical: 15,
                      ),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Helvetica(
                        text: DateFormat('dd LLLL yyyy')
                            .format(DateTime.parse(key)),
                        color: const Color(0xff546889),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

i've tried to add customscrollview but it's still loading even i'm not doing scrolling or load more action on the screen
can anyone help me please i've been stuck for so long